# Is a word with symbols on the right side a hash key?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, literals

In

```
before_action :find_item, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

link_to "Delete", item_path(@item), method: :delete, data: { confirm: "Are you sure?"}
```

I'm not sure what the words with a symbol on the right side:

```
only: ...

method: ..., data: ...
```

represents. I understand that these are parameters of the methods, but if these were hash keys, I don't know why there aren't any curly braces.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you use a hash as the last argument for a method, Ruby allows you to omit curly braces which makes argument lists look a lot nicer. Those calls translates to

```
before_action(:find_item, {only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]})

<%= link_to("Delete", item_path(@item), {method: :delete, data: { confirm: "Are you sure?"}}) %>
```

Comment: Indeed. You could use the standard hash notation (`:only => [...]`)  to make it even clearer.

Answer (score 0):

the words with `:` before the word are just symbols
those that have it after are the symbol with a value

```
method: :delete
```

in this example the `method` has the value of an (empty) symbol `:delete`
it would be equivalent to writing it as `{ :method => :delete }`